# view contents of HTMLElement in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a `HTMLElement` and I'd like to view the contents of the object. A simple for loop followed by printing doesn't work as it wont convert to a primative type. I'm wondering how else can I do this with ease?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the `innerHTML`? Or do you want to list the properties of the element? Also, where do you want to see the "content"? In the console for debugging? In a website?

Comment: I'd like the source basically.. whichever one that is.. e.g `<div>... etc... </div>` I'd like it in the console for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

console.log(focusElement.innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't just chrome, but I usually have something like this if I want debugging in my application:

```
<script>
    var debug = true;

    function log(msg) {
        if(debug) {
            try {
                console.log(msg);
            } catch(e) {
                try {
                    throw new Error(msg);
                } catch(e) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    log("Debug mode is turned on");
    log($("#test"));   
</script>
```

```
<div id="test" style="display:none;">this came from a div</div>
```

### --> [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/PEDBh/1/) <--